# R remove character

Tags: regex, r, string

I have a character vector

```
var1 <- c("pine trees", "dense forest", "red fruits", "fruit's colors")
```

I want all the s in plurals to be made singular. The desired answer is:

```
  var1 <- c("pine tree", "dense forest", "red fruit", "fruit color")
```

How can it be done without using additional packages?

Thanks

Comment: If the goal is to remove the pluralization then why does fruit's get changed to fruit?

Comment: You might consider "regex" as a tag for questions like this.

Comment: Just be aware of proper singular words that end with an `s` (e.g. class, floss, and even jeans) that will be affected by all suggested solutions.

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to do this?

Comment: So you really need a more robust solution.  For example you wouldn't want to convert busses to busse.

Comment: How many unique words are in var1?

Comment: **please do not destroy the text of questions which already have upvoted answers**

Answer (score 3):

You can use gsub

```
gsub("s$", "", var1)
```

## Edit: Response to edited question

My first solutions worked but not well, after the question is been edited and as a result my first solution was even worse. Maybe this code can solve the problem.

```
gsub("'s|s$", "", var1)
```

Comment: What about `"fruit's colors"`?

Comment: I didn't see it because it was not there. The question is been edited after my answer.

Comment: The OP's example contradicts the question, since it is not about plural. And if it is not about plural, specially tailored answers won't be of use anyway.

Comment: @SabDeM no, it wasn't

Answer (score 2):

```
var1 <- c("pine trees", "dense forest", "red fruits", "fruit's colors")

gsub("'?s\\b", "", var1)

#"pine tree"    "dense forest" "red fruit"    "fruit color"
```

Answer (score 2):

(Creating an answer instead of a comment. Admins - move it to comments if you feel so).

For the same problem some 7 months ago, I ended up with the following logic:

1. split all strings in `var1` into separate words, unlist, drop all
   numeric values, tidy up a little bit
2. select only words that ended
   with an `s`
3. went thru the list in two passes: a) run it against a
   dictionary, e.g. enable2k to see if there were plain typos, b) manually eliminated proper words that ended with an `s`.

3b is, of course, tedious, but it reduces the high chance of "breaking" good words.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
gsub("\\'s|s$","",var1)
```

Comment: In my OS the `'` does not need to be escaped. Do you need to escape it?